# How to parse a JSON which has only numbers

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am still learing python and I am trying to parse data from a JSON which looks like

```
{"297050": [[12, 137], [193, 776]], "297056": [[12, 203]]
```

but I cannot find a way to read it such as I get like

> For entry 297050 this is the list [12, 137], [193, 776] 
>   For entry  297056 this is the list [12, 203]

I tried something like that

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

input_file = open ('file_JSON.txt')
json_array = json.load(input_file)
store_list = []


for obj in json_array :
    print obj,json_array[obj]
```

which gives me the obj and the array for each one

> 297050 [[12, 137], [193, 776]]

but I would like to actually be able to print each one of the elements that appear inside for instance the json_array[obj][0]...etc

Comment: Please provide expected result

Comment: Because these are nested arrays, you won’t be able to get the values without doing a little more work. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use nested for loops.. what exactly you should print depends on how you expect your output to look.. but you could try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json

data = '{"297050": [[12, 137], [193, 776]], "297056": [[12, 203]]}'

data = json.loads(data)

for k, v in data.items():
    print(k)
    for list_of_ints in v:
        for integer in list_of_ints:
            print(integer)
```

Result:

```
297050
12
137
193
776
297056
12
203
```

Explanation:

We load in the sample json, and use `items` to iterate over it's key value pairs. Now our keys are in `k` and the outermost list is in `v`. `v` is a list, and a list of lists.. so we iterate that as `list_of_ints`. And finally we loop over each of those lists, printing out the innermost integers as we go.

If what you want as your output is this:

For entry 297050 this is the list [12, 137], [193, 776] For entry 297056 this is the list [12, 203]

Then we can just modify the script a little.. and get rid of a lot of the loops.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json

output = "For entry {} this is the list {}"
data = '{"297050": [[12, 137], [193, 776]], "297056": [[12, 203]]}'

data = json.loads(data)

for k, v in data.items():
    lists_with_commas = ", ".join([str(x) for x in v])
    print(output.format(k, lists_with_commas), end=" ")
```

Output

```
For entry 297050 this is the list [12, 137], [193, 776] For entry 297056 this is the list [12, 203]
```

Explanation:

We use a template string.. it has `{}` where we want to put stuff so we can run `.format` on it later.

We only need the keys and the innermost lists. So we only need the one `for` loop. We make sure we get the commas in the example by using `.join` and inside there we do a list comprehension, which turns all the lists into strings inside `v`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. To get the values out of list in a linear way.

```
from itertools import chain

j = {"297050": [[12, 137], [193, 776]], "297056": [[12, 203]]}

for k in j:
     print(k)
     print('\t' + ', '.join(map(str, chain(*j[k]))))
```